# Attaching multiple listeners to views in android?

Tags: android, events, onclicklistener

Is it possible to attach multiple onClick listeners to buttons in android? 
Example:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(listener1);
btn1.setOnCliclListener(listener2);
```

And when the button is clicked onClick event of both `listener1` and `listener2` are triggered?

In normal GUI applications I know that we can attach more than one event handler for an event. Is it possible for android too or is there any restrictions?

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Android only supports one registered listener in general. However, you can easily create a listener that simply forwards the events to other listeners using the composite pattern.

Comment: Could you please let me know any references for this?

Comment: @Lalith: The composite pattern is a classic design pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: Hmm.. the main reason i need multiple event handlers for single event is I plan to create a library which will be used by other android developers. It is supposed to be initialized somewhere and it goes all by itself attaching required event handlers to each View item. I did this in silverlight easily so was wondering if htat is possible.

Comment: @Lalith: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Got it! but not so sure if I could follow this approach. Thanks any way !

Comment: For an example of how to do this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465204/how-can-i-set-up-multiple-listeners-for-one-event

Comment: @Lalith, I'm also doing the same, so can you give me more insights about implementation. 
How did you implement this?

Comment: John Kamau gives a code example for this below.  But it's probably better practice to just have one onClickListener that calls multiple functions.

Answer (score 4):

Should someone bump into a similar problem, try this out:

```
private void setClickListeners(View view, List<View.OnClickListener> clickListeners){
    view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        for(View.OnClickListener listener: clickListeners){
            listener.onClick(v);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to achieve this would be simply do:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {  
   listener1.onClick(v);
   listener2.onClick(v);
}})
```

Or call listener2.onClick(v) inside the definition of your listener1

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'll do in Kotlin:

```
arrayListOf(
        view1,
        view2,
        view3
    ).forEach { it.setOnClickListener { /*do stuff here*/ } }
```

very readable, and copy-paste error safe.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        // do this
    }else if(v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        // do that
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's question was two listeners for one button

Answer (score -5):

Nope, for example just do this :

**Set Listener:**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**Implement Method:**

```
public void Onclick(View arg0){

   // check your id and do what you want
}
```