# Android: Attaching multiple click listeners to Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

As I'm creating a library and I wanted to track the button clicks from the application using that library(kind of analytics clicks tracking library). So I have tried so many things and those didn't work for me. I have gone through the below link and I came to know that we can add multiple listeners using the composite pattern.

[Attaching multiple listeners to views in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542627/attaching-multiple-listeners-to-views-in-android)

Please help me here to achieve my requirement.

Here is the code, which I have tried

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_demo);

    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameFragment, new FragmentA());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.buttonDemo);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("test", "Button Click 1");
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("test", "Button Click 2");
            /*Field field = null;
            try {
                Log.e("test", "CLASS NAME: "+v.getClass().getName());
                field = Class.forName(v.getClass().getName()).getDeclaredField("mOnClickListener");
                View.OnClickListener retrievedListener = (View.OnClickListener) field.get(v);
                Log.e("test", ""+retrievedListener.toString());
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("test", "Exception: NoSuchFieldException");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("test", "Exception: ClassNotFoundException");
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("test", "Exception: IllegalAccessException");
            }*/


            ClickListener listenerCollector = new ClickListener();
            listenerCollector.addOnclickListener(this);
        }
    });



}
```

}

another class

```
public class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
private ArrayList<View.OnClickListener> clickListeners = new ArrayList<>();

public void addOnclickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
    clickListeners.add(listener);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    for(View.OnClickListener l : clickListeners){
        l.onClick(v);
        Log.e("test", "onclick from composite click");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you can add, what you are trying to achieve little bit more, it will be easy to help.

Comment: @Suresh can you please post your code also?

Comment: does this link answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465204/how-can-i-set-up-multiple-listeners-for-one-event

Comment: @Keshav1234, I have gone through the above link, It is not clear for me.

Comment: @Suresh ok please post code of what you have tried and understood from other resources.

Comment: @Keshav1234, I have updated my question with code, which I'm trying

Comment: @Suresh what is not working with this code? can you please explain that?

Comment: Here is my requirement, I need to get onclickListener in another class ("ClickListener") also. When I click the button from MainActivity it should print below log
Log.e("test", "Button Click 2"); as well as need to print Log.e("test", "onclick from composite click"); from another class also. Something wrong I did here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

Add the following in `onCreate` of `MainActivity` and `onCreate` of another class:

Make `Clicklistener` class a `singleton` so that it contains single object at any time.

```
ClickListener listenerCollector = new ClickListener.getInstance();
listenerCollector.addOnclickListener(this);
```

In the `onClick` of your button in `MainActivity` add the following:

```
for (ClickListener listener: listenerCollector.clickListeners){
      listener.onClick();
}
```

Remove for loop in `ClickListener OnClick` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wanted to track this click listener in my Android Library class(i.e not an activity class). Will it work?

Comment: Library can have an activity. You can build a module by implementing this and use it.